# How to terminate the input of std::cin?

Tags: c++, json, cin, istream

[nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#serialization--deserialization) shows an example as below

```
// deserialize from standard input
json j;
std::cin >> j;
```

When I input, it doesn't terminate as I expected. For example, I type `1` and return with keyboard, I hope json is a number 1. But it let me continue to input. How to terminate the input of std::cin?

Comment: What was your input

Comment: instead of 1 can you try with data in json format .. like`{"happy":true}`

Comment: Did you see issue #367?

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Tried. Same problem.

Comment: `j<<std::cin;` from gif shown in github ..

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Doesn't work also

Comment: raise an issue in repository may be they can help ...

Comment: It looks to me like it expects to see the end of the input stream. So it will read until it gets an EOF

Comment: @rici How to input EOF with keyboard?

Comment: Windows: control-z  unix: control-d at the beginning of a line

Comment: @rici Got it. Before I tried control-z only. It doesn't work. If input `enter` , `control-z` and `enter` again. It works.